Bootstrap use in angular17 application
How to add bootstrap in angular-17 application from CLI
I tried installing bootstrap globally using npm install -g bootstrap
and then added required lines in angular.json in style and script.
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
Then added below line in style.css file
    @import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

Install bootstrap (locally) using below command, run this command in the same place as your projects package.json
npm i bootstrap

After that go to angular.json and copy paste the below code, for including the CSS and JS required for bootstrap!
        ...
        "scripts": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"],
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/global_styles.css"
        ],
        ...

Then place your sample bootstrap code in main.ts and it will start working!
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
   <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz demo
